# How to draw a line over current screen?

Tags: android, view

i have a linear layout which is linked to an activity and i want to draw a line over it from a view class using addview but the problem is that when i add using addview then it shift the whole screen upwards. I want to draw a line at specific position without changing the layout. if this can we done by any other method that will be ok. Please help. Also tell that how to remove a Addview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:weightSum="7"
android:background="@mipmap/untitled_3"
android:id="@+id/multiplayer_game_activity"
tools:context="com.bussiness.vidit.ticktacknoughtsandcrosses.Multiplayer_game">


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.18"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reset_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name_tv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name_tv"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="RESET"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="                        "
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/turn_tv"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/turn_tv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/turn_tv"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/turn_tv" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/turn_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TURN - "
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.87">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv3"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.68">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv4"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv5"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv6"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_weight="0.80">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv7"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv8"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv9"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/cross" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cross_win_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cross_win_tv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/circle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cirle_win_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:text="Draws"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/draw_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:textSize="25dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the mockup of what you want to draw and your layout file ?

Comment: thanks for fast reply. I just want to draw a simple line (start x, start y, end x, end y)

Comment: At which position you want to add the new line ? If you are adding in a linear layout and its orientation is vertical then it will add the line below the views.

Comment: found something working - DrawView obj=new DrawView(this);
        addContentView(obj, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(1000,1000)); but plz tell me how to remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get exactly what you want. I assume that you want to draw a "1 px line". If so, you can do it like this:

```
<View 
   android:background="#ffffff" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="1dp" />
```